# Fetch the "Alias" field for Joomla menu item

Tags: php, joomla

Is there a way to get the Alias field of a main menu item in Joomla 1.5 from mod_mainmenu module? I know you can access the menu using this code:

```
$menu = JSite::getMenu();
```

I need to use the Alias field to hold a sub-title for the menu item. Is it possible to fetch this from the `modMainMenuXMLCallback()` function in mod_mainmenu? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$menu = JSite::getMenu();
$alias = $menu->getItem($id)->alias;  // if you have id of menu


$menu = JSite::getMenu();
$alias = $menu->getActive()->alias;  // alias of active menu
```

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav. By the way, is there a way to loop over the menu items and get their IDs and other properties?

Comment: Here's a way to fetch the alias when you don't have the ID: `$menu = JSite::getMenu(); $arr = (array)$menu->getActive(); $alias = $arr['alias'];`

Comment: @Alex : I have written it as second option.